# Can I invoke Amazon Alexa Skill without user interaction?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have worked on the Skill that can be invoked by an Alexa command. Now I want to know if I can invoke the Skill without an Alexa command? Can a Skill be invoked by itself by some mechanism?

Comment: I am looking for the same answer. Something like invoke a skill when your paired phone is near Alexa.

Answer (score 0):

There must be some type of activity to invoke skill, otherwise there is no mechanism yet to invoke automatically at the time of answering your question.

We have confirmed by the official team of Alexa.